# HttpRequest object after session times out for a web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I wanted to know how request objects behave when a session is time out.
To be more specific I came across to one scenario, for which I am not able to figure out what is happening exactly.

The scenario is like this,

I have a login page for my web application with username and password fields. I have set the time out to 10 minutes for my app.
I am on the login page doing nothing for 15 minutes, so the session is timed out.

Now on the login I put the user name and password and hit submit. The page is getting refreshed instead of submitting.

So can I say upon session time out,the request object also times out?

Comment: You may need to post some minimal code to better exemplify your problem. Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not add any code to your question, my explanations should be taken with a grain of salt.

IMHO, you are starting the session when a client requests the login page (before he submits the login page) and also you've set it so that a request belonging to a timeout session will be redirected to login page.

So if the result is not to your liking you have to change some of the above.

But again, for a better answer, you have to show us some code.

And for your question about request time out. No it did not time out. It only times out if the server does not respond in time (which is a different kind of time out)

I added some Java code partials which I am using to direct requests belonging to sessions which are timed out to Login page. By the way I also should add that requests which did not require a session is handled before this redirection.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
boolean hasActiveSession;
if (session == null) {
  hasActiveSession = false;
  //...
}
//...
if (!hasActiveSession) {
  request.setAttribute("alert","Your session has timed out");
  request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nuri for the response :). 
So even though the session is timed out, the request can be served by container, right?
That means if we take your example, if user's session is timed out user will be forwarded to login page. On the login page now, the user again waits for let's say 15 mins (session time out again). And now the user enters the username and password and press submit.

Will this request be processed, let's say by a filter that has been configured for login url pattern? Or a new request for login page goes to the container (which causes refresh)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you open a new session while redirecting and the user again waits till new session time outs, yes he will again be redirected. In your case is new session really necessary for serving the login page? If not, start a new session after login is completed and only redirect the requests which should have a valid session.